# MongoDB fails starting as a service on CentOS 7

Tags: mongodb, centos

I've a Google cloud VM with MongoDB server running for many months. Today the VM restarted and MongoDB won't run as a service (i can run it mannualy as a process and starts OK).

- OS: CentOS 7
- MongoDB Verion: 3.2.16

**The error thrown**:

```js
>sudo service mongod start

Starting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

So if i run "systemctl status mongod.service":

```js
>sudo systemctl status mongod.service

mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-02-05 18:05:49 UTC; 1min 20s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3755 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 05 18:05:49 todoturnos-testing systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database....
Feb 05 18:05:49 todoturnos-testing runuser[3762]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user mongod by (uid=0)
Feb 05 18:05:49 todoturnos-testing mongod[3755]: Starting mongod: [FAILED]
Feb 05 18:05:49 todoturnos-testing systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 05 18:05:49 todoturnos-testing systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
Feb 05 18:05:49 todoturnos-testing systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Feb 05 18:05:49 todoturnos-testing systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

If i run "journalctl -xe"

```js
>sudo journalctl -xe

Feb 05 18:09:58 todoturnos-testing sudo[3827]: janokpodelmundi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/service mongod start
Feb 05 18:09:58 todoturnos-testing polkitd[348]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3847:870363 (system bus name :1.242 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /or
Feb 05 18:09:58 todoturnos-testing systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database....
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
Feb 05 18:09:58 todoturnos-testing runuser[3860]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user mongod by (uid=0)
Feb 05 18:09:58 todoturnos-testing runuser[3860]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user mongod
Feb 05 18:09:58 todoturnos-testing mongod[3853]: Starting mongod: [FAILED]
Feb 05 18:09:58 todoturnos-testing systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 05 18:09:58 todoturnos-testing systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Feb 05 18:09:58 todoturnos-testing systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Feb 05 18:09:58 todoturnos-testing systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Feb 05 18:09:58 todoturnos-testing polkitd[348]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3847:870363 (system bus name :1.242, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent,
Feb 05 18:10:00 todoturnos-testing sudo[3866]: janokpodelmundi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
lines 2280-2321/2321 (END)
```

Where "janokpodelmundi" is my username.

So, i have disabled SELINUX as i know it could be related with this problem, but didn't resolved it.
I've also changed the "pid" file location to ensure the permissions are OK,and had disabled forking in the config as well.

**My mongodb config**:

```js
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork d run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongo/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
 bindIp: 0.0.0.0   # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
```

The mongodb log is empty, and it's not generating rows at any time.

I have been trying many alternatives i've found on internet but the problem persists.

Any help would be great.

**Solution**:
After trying the "mongod -f /path-to-config-file" and getting the "incorrect YAML" error at line 29, i pasted from original mongo conf the lines 26-29:

```js
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0  #
```

After that i tried again the "mongod -f path-to-config-file" and succeed.

Comment: Have you tried starting `mongod` from the command line `mongod -f <path_to_conf>/conf_file_name.conf` with the forking disabled

Comment: It should be `systemLog:` your missing an `s`, or is that just a typo...

Comment: I had a typo pasting here... the config file has the "systemLog" correctly. I tried the mongod -f with the config file and it throws the following error: Error parsing YAML config file: yaml-cpp: error at line 29, column 2: end of map not found

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/7174775/trdrake are you using spaces in your YAML file and not tabs? Seems that you have a funny character or indent within your conf file. The easiest way to debug this is to start off with a basic conf file and add in options and make sure your indents etc are correct before adding another option

Comment: Okay, so i just deleted the file and created it again with all the information copied and pasted from the original mongo branch and it worked. You were right, it seems there is a funny character somewhere. Problem solved, you saved my life, thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe update your OP with the YAML error :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML files require spaces for indentation and not tabs. Seems that you have a funny character/indent within your conf file. The easiest way to debug this is to start off with a basic conf file and add in options and make sure your indents etc are correct before adding another option

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above , the issue may be caused because files isn't in Yaml format
run :
**mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf**

you will get in what line the issue is (fix the extra spaces and issue will be solved)